# Banner is obscuring content on Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams, banner

When visiting one of my Teams, I'm greeted with a banner to take a feedback survey. I might want to take it later, so I don't want to dismiss it, but right now it obscures the top part of the main screen. I can't scroll up any further.

[image]

It would be hard to tap the 'Ask question' button on a touchscreen, and on narrow screens it's downright impossible:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report! It's not currently fixed but will be by the time we roll out another banner.